# How to export an application and its SHIM in a MSI package...?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-installer, packaging, shim

I have an application(.exe) and its SDB file, and now I want to bundle it into an MSI package for deployment as a installer. How can I create the msi package? Are there any tools? can it be done in Visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). Depending on what your installer has to do, it is the best way to get an msi.